# jQuery.cycle change div background image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

jQuery newbie!

I am having real trouble getting the Cycle plugin to change the background image of a div rather than cycle through slides. My div has other content which I don't want to change.

Is there another plugin out there that I should be using to achieve this? Help most appreciated on this.

Comment: Show us some code, maybe we could help ya.

Comment: Ok so maybe I asked the wrong question. Can Cycle be used to change the background image of a div? I have got it working cycling through a number of divs using slideExpr: 'div.mainimage' but this means that I need multiple mainimage div's with different backgrounds but the same content.

Answer (score 1):

This page should help you:

http://www.magneticwebworks.com/jquery-rotating-page-background/

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the method Marshall recommended: http://jsfiddle.net/petarsubotic/299Wr/

CSS

```
#wrapper {
position: absolute;
overflow:hidden;
height: 333px; /* optional */
background: black; /* optional */
}
#content {
position:relative;
z-index:999;
float:left;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  /* optional */
padding:1em;  /* optional */
margin: 1em;  /* optional */
color:white;  /* optional */
}
#bg_containers {
position:absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content"> 
The background image behind this can be any size, so although it may not cover your entire screen in this case, you can make it cover as much or as little of the screen as you like. Just adjust the size of the #bg_containers, and of course, you can also have the background tile if you like as well.
</div>
<div id="bg_containers" >
<div><img src="http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg"/>    </div>
<div><img src="http://www.mtsu.edu/urban/images/urban1.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```