# How to cycle the background image of div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Here's the link to the best solution I could find as a starting point:
[jQuery.cycle change div background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948395/jquery-cycle-change-div-background-image)
which pointed to ->
http://www.magneticwebworks.com/jquery-rotating-page-background/

Here's the link to what I would like the finished product to look like (but with rotating background)
wordpress.danielatwork.com/pilotfish

Here's the link to the page I'm currently working on and stuck at in terms of code:
test.beeptech.com

I feel as though I'm close of course... the image is positioned correctly, the size is a little off but that's an aside, I just can't get the original div/text to stay put above the background.

Many many thanks for your help.  I'm really enjoying the challenge of building a website to look and feel a certain way, and now I realize how difficult the fine tuning process can be.

-Dan

ps. I had to make a few of the links 'dry' as my current status will not allow more than two active hyperlinks per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a problem with `z-index` .
Just peeped out your reference link: http://www.magneticwebworks.com/demo/. They use `z-index:999` for their **Text-Container**.

You should use a bigger value for your text-container then your Image container.
Play with z-index, it will be solved.

Comment: Thank you.  I added z-index: -1 to the image container and along with the advise from Patrick Koulalis (which got the background in proper position) all looks well.  A lesson aside; I spent hours working on this problem over two late nights, and in retrospect I should have slept more and used stackoverflow.com a lot sooner! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/ With a bit of editing of the css you should be able to achieve what you are looking for with this.

Answer (score 0):

your div.bg1-3 have a position: absolute; value that is preventing them to display correctly.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Koulalis!  I wish I could have chosen two 'accepted answers' as yours was also very helpful in getting the format to work.  Amazing response time and I'm now a firm believer in the power of stackoverflow! :)